# Fetch the lastest ban from the audit logs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to code a discord bot that looks for the latest ban in the audit logs.
I currently have:

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', guild => {
  guild.fetchAuditLogs().then(logs => {
    logs.entries.filter(l => l.action === 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD')
      .forEach(log => {
        if (Date.now() - log.createdTimestamp > 1000) return

        const logsChannel = guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'bans-logs')
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setDescription(`**New Ban**
            **${log.executor.tag}** banned **${log.target.tag}**`)
          .setColor("RED")
          .setTimestamp(log.createdTimestamp)

        logsChannel.send(embed)
      })
  })
})
```

I thought about using `.first()` because this is a Collection, but I'm not sure the logs are ordered by date...

Comment: I don't know. I know the output `messages.fetch` is organized by date so you should probably try it

Comment: I'll try it out thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to fetch the audit logs and sort them by date since, as you also said, I'm not sure you'll always get them in chronological order.
You need to:

- Fetch all the audit logs
- Sort the entries by date: you can use the [Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you find in the [`createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdAt) properties
- Get the latest one, which should now be the first

Here's how I would do it:

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', guild => {
  guild.fetchAuditLogs()
    .then(logs => {
      let ban = logs.entries
        .filter(e => e.action === 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD')
        .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt) // Reverse chronological order
        .first() // Get the first, which is the latest

      // You can now send your embed using the entry stored in 'ban'
    })
})
```